# Tensor product and compositum of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $E/k$, $F/k$ be two arbitrary field extensions of $k$. My question is:

1. Is there a field extension $M/k$ s.t. $E/k$, $F/k$ are subextensions of $M/k$? Alternatively, can we talk about compositum fields without assuming a larger field?
2. If the answer to the above question is yes, can we construct such a $M/k$ explicitly (by tensor product, direct product, localization, quotient etc.)?
3. Is the $k-$algebra $E\otimes_k F $ never the zero ring?

Comment: The tensor product of two nonzero vector spaces is nonzero.

Comment: The compositum always exists. See for instance *Algèbre*, Bourbaki, Section V.2.4, Cor. to Prop. 4.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you seem to have realized the concept of a compositum is a bit troubling if we are not working inside a bigger field. Anyway, here come a few quick and dirty answers:

1+2) Yes (up to identification). The tensor product $E\otimes_k F$ is a commutative $k$-algebra. If $I$ is a maximal ideal in there (call upon Zorn's lemma to get the existence), then $M=E\otimes_k F/I$ is a field. The mappings $e\mapsto e\otimes 1 +I$ and $f\mapsto 1\otimes f +I$ are then homomorphisms of $k$-algebras, and thus injective (scores of details to check here). Therefore we can identify their images with $E$ and $F$ respectively. However, the choice of $I$ may make quite a difference. For example, if $E$ and $F$ are isomorphic (think: $\mathbf{Q}(\root 3\of 2)$ and $\mathbf{Q}(\omega\root3\of2)$, $\omega=(-1+i\sqrt3)/2$), then their images are equal for an appropriate choice of $I$, but may intersect trivially for another one.

[Edit: It is possible that the images of $E$ and $F$ never intersect trivially. A trivial intersection occurs in my example case, but clearly not always. Sorry about any possible confusion this error in the original version may have created.]

3) No. This never happens. The tensor product of two non-trivial vector spaces is never zero. You get a basis for the tensor product from pairwise elementary tensors of basis elements of the factor spaces. When we mod out a maximal ideal as above, some linear dependencies may or may not be introduced (the ideal may be zero).

Answer (score 16):

Consider the tensor product $A=E\otimes _kF$.

a) The $k$-algebra $A$ is nonzero because any choice of bases 
$(e_i)_{i \in I}$ of $E$ and  $(f_j)_{j \in J}$ of $F$ will yield a basis 
$(e_i \otimes f_j)_{(i,j) \in I\times J}$ of $A=E\otimes _kF$ ( This answers your question 3.)

b) The set $Spec(A)$ of prime ideals of the non-zero ring $A$ is thus non empty.
Consider a prime ideal  $P \subset A$, the quotient $A/P$ and the fraction field $k(P)=Frac(A/P)$.
The compositon of  $k$-morphisms $E \to A=E\otimes _k F \to A/P \to k(P) $ is necessarily injective (since  $E$ is a field!) and exhibits $k(P)$ as an extension of $E$. Similarly $k(P)$ is canonically an extension of $F$. And finally $k(P)$ is a compositum of $E$ and $F$. (This answers your question 2. and part of your question 1. For the rest of 1. see c) below)

c) Every compositum of the extensions $E,F$ of $k$ is obtained (up to isomorphism) by the procedure above applied to a suitable prime $P\in Spec(A)$. Moreover different primes yield non-isomorphic extensions. So $Spec(A) =Spec(E\otimes _kF)$ exactly classifies the isomorphism classes of composita of $E$ and $F$. In particular, since 
$Spec(A)$ has in general more than one element, it does not make sense to talk of the compositum of $E$ and $F$ in the abstract, that is if $E$ and $F$ are not given as subfields of some extension of $k$. (This answers the rest of your question 1.)

d) A paraphrase of the above is that we have described the set underlying the affine scheme $Spec(E\otimes _k F)$. More generally, the description in c) is the key point in the description of  the set underlying the fiber product $X\times _S Y$ of two arbitrary schemes $X,Y$ over an arbitrary scheme $S$.

**Addendum: what is a compositum?**
Given two field extensions $k\to E, k\to F$, let me explain in elementary terms (that is without tensor products) what a compositum of these is.
It is the data of a field extension $k \to K$ *and* of a pair of $k$-morphisms ($E\to K, F\to K$), subject to the condition that the union of the images of $E$ and $F$ in $K$ generate (in the field sense !) the field $K$. An isomorphism of two such extensions is an isomorphism $K\to K'$of $k$-extensions making obvious diagrams commute.
The key point to keep in mind is that the extension $k\to K$ alone does *not* determine the compositum.
This is perfectly illustrated by Matt's and Pierre-Yves's exchange  in the comments where ( a little confusingly!)   the three extensions $E,F,K$ of $k=\mathbb R$ are the inclusion $k=\mathbb R \to K=\mathbb C$  and they have  two  composita with the $same$  extension $k\to K$ which are nevertheless *non-isomorphic*: this is possible  because the composita have different pairs of  $k$-morphisms  ($E\to K, F\to K$) in their data.

Comment: To see if I got it right: If you take $k=\mathbb R$, $E=F=\mathbb C$, you get precisely two non-isomorphic composita.

Comment: @Pierre: Dear Pierre-Yves, Yes, but you have to interpret the concept of isomorphism appropriately: abstractly, the two composita are both isomorphic to $\mathbb C$, but they are realized as composita in two different ways: in the first way $E$ and $F$ are both mapped to $\mathbb C$ identically; in the second way, $E$ (say) is mapped to $\mathbb C$ identically, but $F$ is mapped via complex conjugation.  Regards,

Comment: Dear @Matt: Thanks for your very clear explanation! Say that $C$ is a compositum of $E$ and $F$ over $k$. Viewing $C$ as a compositum means viewing it as a $E\otimes_k F$-algebra, whereas viewing it as an extension of $k$ means viewing it as a $k$-algebra. Right?

Comment: @Pierre-Yves: Dear Pierre-Yves, Yes, that's exactly right.  Regards,

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for c),d),the addendum and the comments!

Comment: Dear Zhe, it was a pleasure.

Comment: @ Georges Elencwajg  In your answer is it true that $k(P)$ is a minimal field containing a copy of $E$ and $F$ ?

Comment: @user371231 Yes it is true. More precisely, the smallest subfield of $k(P)$ containing both the image of $E$ and  the image of $F$  is $k(P)$.

Comment: @ Georges Elencwajg Can you please tell me how you are thinking it as the minimal field containing a copy of both $E$ and $F$ ?

Comment: @user371231 Hint: the images of $E$ and $F$ together generate $A$ as a ring. Same for  $A/P$ .

Comment: @ Georges Elencwajg Great Hint. Thank you.