# Minimal subfield of two fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $\Bbb F \subset \Bbb K_1 , \Bbb K_2 \subset \Omega$ all fields.

Denote by $\Bbb K_1\Bbb K_2$ the minimal field containing both $\Bbb K_1$ and $\Bbb K_2$

I need to prove that if $[\Bbb K_1:\Bbb F]$ and $[\Bbb K_2:\Bbb F]$ both finite then $[\Bbb K_1 \Bbb K_2 : \Bbb F]\le [\Bbb K_1:\Bbb F][\Bbb K_2:\Bbb F]$.

Not sure how to do it, hints/partial solution would be great.

Thanks !

Comment: Start from definitions: $\dim_F K_i = d_i, i = 1,2$.  Construct bases $b_i$ for $K_i$, then what can be said about $span(b_1 \cup b_2)$?

Comment: Are $\mathbb K_1$ and $\mathbb K_2$ already subfields of the same field, or can you choose how they're going to embed in $\mathbb K_1\mathbb K_2$ yourself?

Comment: [Closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56876/11619) if you don't have $\Omega$ available to begin with.

Comment: The title does not reflect the question.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $\;\{v_1,...,v_n\}\,,\,\,\{w_1,...,w_m\}\;$ are basis of $\;\Bbb K_1/\Bbb F\,,\,\,\Bbb K_2/\Bbb F\;$ resp., then

$$\;\Bbb K_1\Bbb K_2=\text{Span}_{\Bbb F}\,\{\,v_iw_j\}_{1\le i\le n,\,1\le j\le m}\;$$

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do exactly that, I can't see why the product would span $\Bbb K_1 \Bbb K_2$

Comment: This works. Assuming that there exists a bigger field $\Omega$ that contains both $\Bbb{K}_1$ and $\Bbb{K}_2$. For otherwise the products $v_iw_j$ are not necessarily defined...

Comment: @Liad Take a product of elements $\;xy\,,\,\,x\in\Bbb K_1\,,\,\,y\in\Bbb K_2\;$ . Then clearly $\;xy\in\text{Span}\,\{v_1w_j\}\;$ . Take now any finite sum with coefficients in $\;\Bbb F\;$ and products as above: it clearly is in the given span...

Comment: $\Bbb K_1 \Bbb K_2$ is the smallest field containing both $\Bbb K_1 $ and $\Bbb K_2$ , why are you looking at products? @DonAntonio

Comment: @Liad you can show that the span described by DonAntonio is closed under products. If that span is taken inside some integral domain, [it follows that the span is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63950/11619). No smaller field can possibly contain both the fields, so you are done.

Comment: And Jyrki is right: the composition of fields requires both fields contained in a bigger one